# Highchart's line color not changing in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, highcharts

I have included a stockChart in a wordpress page. Changing the color of the markers of a series works. However, changing the line color does not have any effect. I suppose that this issue is rooted in the interplay between highcharts and wordpress, as the below code displays as expected when opened in a browser. Has anyone run into this problem yet?

Minimal example that shows this behaviour:

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

<script>
chart = Highcharts.stockChart(container, {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'testplot',
    },
    series: [
        {
           name: 'testdata',
           data: [[1000000, 1],[1010000, 2],[1020000, 3],[1030000, 4]],
           color: '#FF0000',
           lineColor: '#000000',
        },    
    ]
});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test another config - where the `color` property defines the line color and marker color will be set in this way:

```
 series: [{
    name: 'testdata',
    data: [
      [1000000, 1],
      [1010000, 2],
      [1020000, 3],
      [1030000, 4]
    ],
    color: '#000000',
        marker: {
            fillColor: '#FF0000'
        }
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/74v9xken/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.fillColor

---

EDIT:

According to the comments: the style was overwritten by SCSS default config - `.highcharts-graph { stroke:#FF7096; }`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Sebastian. Unfortunately, the line color is still not black. Same behaviour as in my minimal example: Markers are red and the line is pink.

Comment: @jppade interesting, are you able to reproduce it somehow? Could you share a sample of your page?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the following link:
https://diadata.org/highcharts-line-test/

Comment: Its seems that your SCSS config `.highcharts-graph { stroke:#FF7096; }` overrides the inline styling.

Comment: That actually solved my problem. It was indeed the wordpress theme's stylefile that overwrote the inline styling. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @jppade I did an update of my answer. Please check it and accept - could be useful for other users.